# Strategy for saving values from controls to a property store on a worker thread

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

Let's say you have a bunch of controls (e.g., edit controls, comboboxes, date-time pickers, etc.), and you'd like to save their values to a property handler (i.e., an `IPropertyStore`), which will then be committed.  And for efficiency, you'd like to do it on a background worker thread.  How might you go about that?

I've read that although it's possible, you should not get values from or set values to GUI controls from a worker thread (using `SendMessage` or any `SendMessage`-based function).

So the only approach I can think of would be to iterate through the (dirty) controls on the UI thread, getting each value, and then for each value post some sort of custom task object to the worker thread, which will set the value to the property store.  I suppose this would also involve a "start" task that tells the worker thread to initiate the `IPropertyStore`, as well as an "end" task that tells the worker thread to commit.

Is that reasonable, or is there a better way?  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What's the problem with SendMessage (or PostMessage)? *"If the specified window was created by the calling thread, the window procedure is called immediately as a subroutine. If the specified window was created by a different thread, the system switches to that thread and calls the appropriate window procedure."* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage#remarks

Comment: Well I've read that a "worker thread must not touch a GUI object." http://flounder.com/workerthreads.htm

Comment: *iterate through the (dirty) controls on the UI thread, getting each value, and then* - yes, correct. *for each value post some sort of custom task object to the worker thread, which will set the value to the property store* - this is wrong. you need call *IPropertyStore::SetValue* from UI thread. and then post *IPropertyStore* object to worked thread **once**

Comment: @RbMm In that scenario, I suppose you'd marshal the `IPropertyStore` pointer?

Comment: no of course. for what ? pass it direct to thread as is. main - that only single thread access interface at time. first this will be UI thread. than worker thread only

Comment: The article you're referencing is kinda old. Today, I would recommend to always use C++20 coroutines, and call it a day. The [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt) library provides both an efficient executor based on the thread pool, as well as convenient helpers to switch between threads as needed.